# Event handler ordering in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view that I am popping up in Xamarin forms, that I want to hide if someone taps outside of the box.  I have a tap gesture recognizer on the parent layout for the list view that handles that.  In Android, it all works good.  If I click off, it closes, but if I click on an element in the list view, it properly selects it.  In iOS, the opposite happens.  The gesture handler on the layout fires first and closes the list view without properly selecting the item.

So my question, is there a way to change the order on how the events are fired?  If not, is there a better alternative to how I'm trying to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ListView.ItemSelected` or `ListView.ItemTapped` then I ran into the exact same issue the other day. The fix for me was to not use either of those and instead attach a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `ViewCell` that is within the `ListView`. I also added an `IsSelected` property to the object that the ViewCell is being bound to so that I could change the background color of the item once it has been clicked.

```
public class SomePage : ContentPage {

    private SomeModel _selectedModel; //It would be best to put this into your ViewModel

    ...

    public SomePage() {

        ListView list = new ListView {
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
                ViewCell cell = new ViewCell {
                    View = new ContentView()
                };

                cell.View.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer {
                    Command = new Command(() => {
                        if(_selectedModel != null) { _selectedModel.IsSelected = false; }

                        SomeModel model = (SomeModel)cell.BindingContext;

                        model.IsSelected = true;
                        _selectedModel = model;
                    })
                }

                return cell;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So an update on this, this solution did work, however I had to set the cell.View before I could add in the GestureRecognizer.  So I just had to do something like cell.View = new ContentView
                {
                    Content = label,
                    Padding = new Thickness(10, 0)
                };   before I could add the gesture recognizer.